# Error instantiating array of type basic_regex

Tags: c++

I have tried all day without any luck...

This works:

```
std::regex pattern ("Test");
```

This doesn't work:

```
std::regex pattern_array[2] {"Test1", "Test2"};
```

Generating the errors:

```
mainprog.cpp:534:47: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"Test1"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::regex {aka std::basic_regex<char>}’

mainprog.cpp:534:47: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"Test2"’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::regex {aka std::basic_regex<char>}’
```

I have tried to make a class with the same structure as `std::regex`, but i am unable to recreate the error (it works perfectly).

I am compiling using gcc 4.7.2 running on Linux.

Documentation for [std::regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex)

Thanks, i highly appreciate any help.

Calle

**Update:**

This is my reconstruction that works:

```
class testclass
{
public:
    testclass(const char* s, bool b = true);
};

testclass::testclass(const char* s, bool b)
{
    printf("Bool %d", b);
}

testclass obj1 ("Test");
testclass obj2[2] {"Test1", "Test2"};
```

Comment: Note the `explicit` part.

Comment: Noted!! "Problem" recreated. Thanks to both of you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
std::regex pattern_array[2] = { std::regex("Test1"), std::regex("Test2") };
```

You need to explicitly construct with the constructor because the regex class uses the `explicit` keyword on its constructor.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Any thoughts on why my solution is failing?
The weird thing is that it works for a single (non-array) object.

This is the constructor that should match:
explicit basic_regex( const CharT* s, flag_type f = std::regex_constants::ECMAScript );

Not that it matters much for my app, but avoiding the 2 extra regex objects would be nice.

Thanks again.

Comment: Does it really cause copy construction? If so,  you can construct them separately (one per line) and then have an array of two pointers to the constructed objects. The original version is failing because it's relying on implicit conversion from const char* to regex.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't call a copy constructor. I will check up on that.
The only thing that bothers me then is that my "reconstruction" works. I will post the code as a reply in case you would like to have a look.

Comment: Your testclass code works because the constructor is not declared `explicit`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Comment: Got it, thanks. I am now getting the same errror with my own class (which is good). I will remember that keyword for sure...

Comment: If the question has been answered to your satisfaction, you probably ought to check the "answered" checkbox. Thanks! :)